# Creating a separate SignalR Hub instance for each client and passing parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am trying to create a page that updates data in real time when ever something changes in the database. I have used SignalR. There is only one hub, here is the code to the hub:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public static int prodId { get; set; }

    public void setProdID(int pid)
    {
        prodId = pid;
    }

    public BidDetailViewModel GetChanges()
    {
        string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conStr);

        SqlDependency.Start(conStr);
        string query = @"select Id,
                                BidDate,
                                BidAmount,
                                BidStatusId,
                                BidderId,
                                ProductId 
                                from [dbo].[Bids] 
                                where ProductId = " + prodId + 
                                " order by BidDate desc ";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        command.Notification = null;
        SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);

        //If Something will change in database and it will call dependency_OnChange method.
        dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

        var bid = new Bid();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            bid.Id = dr.GetInt32(0);
            bid.BidDate = DateTime.Now; //fake value, dont need it
            bid.BidAmount = dr.GetFloat(2);
            bid.BidStatusId = dr.GetInt32(3);
            bid.BidderId = dr.GetString(4);
            bid.ProductId = dr.GetInt32(5);

            //Break after reading the first row
            //Using this becasue we can not use TOP(1) in the query due to SignalR restrictions
            break;
        }
        connection.Close();
        var vm = new BidDetailViewModel
        {
            HighestBid = bid,
            NoOfBids = -1
         //NoOfBids is no longer needed, assigning a random value of -1
         //will remove it later, just testing rn
        };

        return vm;
    }

    private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change) SendNotifications();
    }

    private void SendNotifications()
    {
        BidDetailViewModel vm = GetChanges();
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();

        //Will update all the client with new bid values
        context.Clients.All.broadcastMessage(vm);
    }
}
```

I am calling the hub in two different pages. First one is `/Home/About` and second is `/Home/About2`. They both have the same JS code except for one change, the prodId being passed in `/Home/About` is `40`, and for `/Home/About2` it's `41`. The JS code is: (This is the code for `/Home/About` as you can see it's sending `40`. Again, `/Home/About2` has the exact same code but with `41`).

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
        var ew = $.connection.myHub;
        //This method will fill all the Messages in case of any database change.
        ew.client.broadcastMessage = function (response) {
            //Changing HTML content here using document.getElementById()
        };

        //This method will fill all the Messages initially
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            ew.server.setProdID(40);
            //Hardcoding the prodID for now, will get it using document.getElementById() later
            //ProdId will be different for each page
            ew.server.getChanges().done(function(response) {
               //Changing HTML content here using document.getElementById()
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

As you can see, I'm setting the `ProdId` in `MyHub` hub by calling the `SetProdID` function. I've set `ProdId` to a static member so I can set it without making an object of the hub. Now If visit `/Home/About`, it sets the `prodId` to `40` (as expected) and I get the results from the query. But, when I visit `\Home\About2` it sets `prodId` to `41` (again, as expected) and I get the results from the query that correspond to parameter `41`.

Now if I update the item with id `41` in the database, both the `/Home/About` and `/Home/About2` pages are updated in real time but with the data that corresponds to item with id `41`. I know this post is gettting really long, but my question is, shouldn't SignalR be making a completely separate instance of `MyHub1` for the two different pages? Is this happening because I've made the `ProdId` a static member? If that's it, how do I set it without making it a static member? I basically want multiple instances of the same `MyHub`, each instance for a completely different `prodId`. Is this possible? or do I have to write multiple hubs (MyHub1, MyHub2, .... MyHubn). The problem with writing multiple hubs is that I don't know how many items there are going to be.

I've also tried passing the `prodId` as a parameter to `GetChanges()` method but I'm not sure what to pass in the `sendNotification()` method that calls the `GetChanges()` method.

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public BidDetailViewModel GetChanges(int pid)
    {
        ............
        string query = @"select Id,
                                BidDate,
                                BidAmount,
                                BidStatusId,
                                BidderId,
                                ProductId 
                                from [dbo].[Bids] 
                                where ProductId = " + pid + 
                                " order by BidDate desc ";
        ...............
    }

    private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change) SendNotifications();
    }

    private void SendNotifications()
    {
        //What do I pass here?
        BidDetailViewModel vm = GetChanges();
        ..............
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to proceed from here on, any pointers would be appreciated! Also, thanks for reading this long post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SignalR hubs are transient. This means that SignalR creates a new hub instance for each request. Note that as a consequence you cannot keep hub specific state in the hub instance (e.g. as in a non-static property) because as soon as your hub method completes the hub will be disposed and the value you stored will be lost.

Your problem is that you store the id in a static variable. Static members are shared across all instances of the given class so if you change it in one instance other instances will see the new value. You can read more about static classes and members in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members).

One way of solving your problem is to keep the state in a static variable on the context that is a `ConcurrentDictionary` where you use the connectionId as a key. You can get the connectionId identifying the client invoking the current hub method with `Context.ConnectionId`.

Comment: Thanks! I figured the static member was the problem. I'm fairly new to SignalR, could you please explain to me how I can pass the prodId over to the hub in such a way that I don't have to make it static?

Comment: See the last paragraph I added. You can identify a connection using the connection id which you can get in your hub method by calling `Context.ConnectionId`. You can now store settings in a dictionary (has to be a ConcurrentDictionary) where you use this connection Id as a key. This dictionary can be a static variable since each connection will update/read the slot it owns rather than the reference to the instance.